# Write alignment and ascii tree to file

Tags: python, file-io, biopython

I am using the `AlignIO` and the `Phylo` functions of the `Biopython` Library to align multiple sequences and create a phylogenetic tree. The documentation is very clear in this regard and I dont have any issues in getting my results. However I dont want to just display the results in when the program runs but also want to save them to a file (preferable different files). However as suspected I get the `TypeError: expected a character buffer object`. I couldnt find any help on SO or through google about writing these results into files.

My code:

```
from Bio import AlignIO, Phylo
align = AlignIO.read("allseqs.aln", "clustal")

alignfile = open("alignfile.txt","w")
print(align)
#alignfile.write(align) -->gives error

tree = Phylo.read("allseqs.dnd","newick")
Phylo.draw_ascii(tree)
```

The `align` result look like this:

```
SingleLetterAlphabet() alignment with 14 rows and 1688 columns
--------------------------------------------...--- M.HpyFIII.dna
--------------------------------------------...--- M.HpyFIV.dna
TTGCATAAAGTTTTTATTATGGAAGCTTTGGAATGTTTGAAAAG...--- M.HpyFII.dna
--------------------------------------------...--- M.HpyFXII.dna
ATGCCTTCAAACGCTCTTTCTATTGAAGAAATCGCTCGCCTAGT...TAA M.HpyFVII.dna
--------------------------------------------...--- M.HpyFV.dna
--------------------------------------------...--- M.HpyFXI.dna
--------------------------------------------...--- M.HpyFORFX.dna
--------------------------------------------...--- M1.HpyFXIII.dna
--------------------------------------------...--- M.HpyFVI.dna
---------------------------------------ATGCA...--- M.HpyFVIII.dna
--------------------------------------------...--- M.HpyFIX.dna
--------------------------------------------...--- M2.HpyFXIII.dna
--------------------------------------------...--- M.HpyFI.dna
```

The Phylogenetic tree looks like this:

```
                                          __________________ M.HpyFI.dna
                                         |
                                         |__________________ M2.HpyFXIII.dna
                                         |
                                         |__________________ M.HpyFII.dna
                                         |
                                         |        __________ M.HpyFIII.dna
                                         |_______|
                                         |       |__________ M.HpyFIV.dna
                                         |
                                         |  ________________ M.HpyFVII.dna
                                         |_|
                                         | |________________ M.HpyFXII.dna
_________________________________________|
                                         |__________________ M.HpyFIX.dna
                                         |
                                         |    ______________ M.HpyFVI.dna
                                         |___|
                                         |   |______________ M.HpyFVIII.dna
                                         |
                                         | __________________ M.HpyFORFX.dna
                                         ,|
                                         ||   _____________ M.HpyFV.dna
                                         ||__|
                                         |   |______________ M.HpyFXI.dna
                                         |
                                         |__________________ M1.HpyFXIII.dna
```

EDITED CODE:

```
from Bio import AlignIO, Phylo,SeqIO
import networkx, pylab

align = AlignIO.read("allseqs.aln", "clustal")
align_write = SeqIO.write(align,"alignment_file.fasta","fasta")

tree = Phylo.read("allseqs.dnd","newick")
with open('phylo_tree.txt', 'wb') as fh:
     Phylo.draw_ascii(tree, file = fh)
```

Comment: Have you read [the documentation](http://biopython.org/DIST/docs/api/Bio.AlignIO-module.html)?

Comment: I cant seem to find anything that helps me write the `ascii tree` as it is. using the `write` function, it converts it into a tuple of tuples with the calculated scores.

Answer (score 0):

It's all in [the](http://biopython.org/DIST/docs/api/Bio.AlignIO-module.html) [documentations](http://biopython.org/wiki/Phylo), as @jonrsharpe mentioned

```
with open('asciout.txt', 'wb') as fh:
    Phylo.draw_ascii(tree, file = fh)

with open("alignfile.txt","w") as alignfile:
    AlignIO.write(align, alignfile, format)
```

Or if you really want the string representation as is:

```
with open("alignfile.txt","w") as alignfile:
    alignfile.write(str(align))
```

`str(align)` is what `print` gets.

Comment: I want the ascii tree as it is ( in the tree format with the dashes).

Comment: and `Phylo.draw_ascii(tree, file = fh)` doesn't provide it? it's not the `write` method. It's the exact `draw_ascii` method, except results are printed to the file instead of `sys.stdout`.

Comment: Nope its doesnt. It gives a tuple with the `sequence id` and `scores`

Comment: @letsc Not on my terminal. Can you edit the question with the exact code you're using?